# Checking if values exists with one statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a list of values and I would like to check if any of the values exists in MySQL with one statement.

```
$tags = "VALUE-IN-MySQL,DOESNT-EXIST1,DOESNT-EXIST2";

$tagArray = explode(",", $tags);
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($tagArray) - 1) . '?';

$tagsCheck = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag IN ($qMarks)");
$tagsCheck -> execute($tagArray);
echo $tagsCheck -> rowCount();
```

The problem with this is that it echo's 1 if at least one exist in the statement, but I wan't to deny the statement even if ONLY ONE value exist in the group, but others don't.

Is this possible?

Comment: not following the question very clear. are you talking about "AND" sql statement? where tag LIKE '?' AND tag LIKE '?' ... or something else?

Comment: @i-- I'm going to have a list of comma delimited values, whether it has 3 values, 4 values, or 5. Either way, its going into a string, which in my case I'm turning into an Array. I'd like to check MySQL if one of those values in the string or array does not exist in the mysql.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a simplistic explode like that. This looks like CSV data, so you should be using [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/str_getcsv) instead. Consider what'd happen if one of those values naturally had a comma in it: `"Hello, Newman",Jerry,Elaine`. you'd end up searching for **FOUR** items, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT count(*) total, * FROM tags WHERE tag IN ($qMarks) GROUP by tag HAVING total > 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on questions above, my script does work. However, it counts how many exists, if none exists then I will do if else check like Madan Sapkota suggested.